# Unable To Access VM instance through external ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I recently created a VM instance on google cloud and installed wordpress on it in order to host my website. It was working fine until yesterday but today when I tried accessing the site with the external ip, it says 'this site can't be reached'. also when i tried to open the ssh terminal in the browser window it says 'Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy failed'. Forgive me if this question is silly.. but i am really new to this. I just followed a youtube tutorial to even get to installing wordpress on the VM..Any help will be appreciated.

I tried to get my website to run and even tried adding the firewall rules but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Your question lacks detail on how the VM is configured, VPC firewall rules, etc. Common problems are 1) too small of a VM and the system is hung - try rebooting 2) the public IP address changed because you are using ephemeral addresses - allocate an IP address 3) your system has crashed - review the cloud logging entries. Try the debugging steps in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.